# ab is not sending requests as fast as I want

Tags: load-testing, apachebench

I want to load test my web app and find out the max requests that it can handle per second, while ab doesn't behave quite the same as I have expected:

when sending requests with a single ab, it can send 2k requests/second, so I expect that starting 2 ab would reach 4k requests/sec, while it turns out that for each ab, it can only reach 1k(which sums to 2k for those two).

Seems that ab is not sending requests as fast as it can be, but sending requests as fast as the server can handle.

Is this an expected behaviour? If yes, any other load test tools that can meet my requirement(send requests as fast as possible)?

Thanks

Comment: seems that lago(http://twitter.github.io/iago/) from twitter is a good alternative, will update my question after testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a loot at Yandex.Tank (https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank).
It can send requests as fast as you need according to specified load scheme, no matter how fast your app is.
You can read how to install and use this here : https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/